# Laptop doesn't boot, fails loading the GRUB bootloader!

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, bootloader

I-m facing a very annoiyng issue with my laptop that has a dual boot system with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04. 
Since I don't know why the GRUB bootloader stopped to work and the laptop can't load. I'm very worried about this problem because I'm working on my thesis with this laptop and I can't access my work in the while.
I'm posting also the report URL made with Boot-Repair>http://paste.ubuntu.com/9734513/

I will appreciate so much suggestions for solving this problem...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "GRUB bootloader stopped to work"? Do you still get into the GRUB menu after a fresh boot? Where does it stop?

Comment: The laptop tries to run the GRUB but it stops and retries in loop before entering GRUB menu.

Comment: But it enters the normal grub menu where you can select an OS?

Comment: No, it fails before.

Comment: Sorry, then I'm afraid you have to wait until somebody with a higher knowledge about Linux / GRUB finds your question... :(

I could only think of reinstalling, but it's more likely to be caused by a wrong configuration which I don't know how to reset.

Comment: Do you mean reinstalling the GRUB?

Comment: No, not really. It would be something you could try if nothing else works, but usually under Ubuntu there is no need of reinstalling anything. I am not sure about GRUB, but I would rather wait a few days if anybody might have a better solution. As I wrote, probably there is something wrong in the configuration files I am not familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe performing the steps described in this popular thread could help you: [repair grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)